# Laptop screen goes white during POST

Tags: laptop, lcd

I have a Clevo laptop. On [**POST**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) the screen goes white -- not instantly, but it begins from the center of the screen as a spot and then it spreads to the entire screen.

The strange part is that in the left bottom corner I can see the start-up menu button of Windows.

I am dual-booting Windows and Linux. The strange part is that the taskbar on my Windows install has been on the top of the screen, not on the bottom, for at least 8 months now.

How is it possible from a cold boot that the GPU or RAM (or something else that I am missing) could have such information?

Besides, if I connect my laptop to an external screen, I see the **POST BIOS** but the laptop white screen (for some seconds) I see what I described above.

**EDIT**:

The question is not why the screen goes white, but why in the white screen appears part of the GUI from Windows -- how is that possible because you are in **pre-boot sequence**?

Comment: I'm finding it a little difficult to understand your question but I suspect that the LCD is physically damaged. However, I would try taking the battery out and leaving it for a minute, then putting it back in and testing it again, just in case something else is going on.

Comment: @James I have add more to the question. I have try that, I even remove the bios battery but it continuous.

Comment: Not clear too much for as your last Edit line confusing me more. Are this happens only when you on Windows or same happen on Linus as well. Is this happen when you booted up the system and come after a while.

Comment: @avirk this is happen when I boot up the system ( POST BIOS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test routines are running ) and some times when I am on Linux or windows.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the GPU nor RAM would persist data after power down, and especially not 8 month old data. This is not an issue with the BIOS or CPU or RAM or GPU holding on to a screenshot of your framebuffer. This is definitely some kind of problem or defect with your LCD.

Most likely, your LCD suffers from severe "burn-in". You disabled the screensaver and let the LCD stay at the Windows desktop for a very long time, hence "burning in" the static GUI elements such as the start menu.

A picture of the behavior would be great, but just from your description, I can tell that it's pretty bad burn-in. Not only CRTs can get burn-in; LCDs suffer from it too. Next time use a screensaver. They're called *screen saver* for a reason.

Comment: I do not thing that is a burn-in because this thing is showed up only in the situation as I describe above, and the there is not even a ghost effect any other time that I am working with this machine. I do not have a screen saver the monitor is closing after 4 minutes

Comment: if you thing that is a burn in explain why there is not a ghost effect